# What happens when you type text inside widget tags in an uibinder template?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I'll give you two examples:

```
<g:Label>asdf</g:Label>
```

This calls setText method on the Label object

and

```
<g:HTMLPanel>asdf</g:HTMLPanel>
```

this creates a new HTMLPanel with asdf as argument.

What are the rules that decide what actually happens?

What if I create a new custom widget?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will not work. You have two options for setting text to a Label, for example:

```
<g:Label text="abcd" />
<g:Label><ui:text>abcd</ui:text></g:Label>
```

Comment: it works if you wrap g:Label in a HTMLPanel. Then the generated class that backs uibinder template calls setText method.